# Determining the number of solutions to $\ln\left(x\right)+\arctan\left(x\right)-x+1=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I got this equation and I can't find a definitive way to find how many solutions it has.

$$\ln\left(x\right)+\arctan\left(x\right)-x+1=0$$

I was able to guess it has $2$ solutions because $\ln(x)$ is "dominant" nearby the Y-axis, and the $-x$ is dominant when $\lim _{x\to \infty }$. But I have no better way than this approximation.

**Is there a way without resorting to the use of limits?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see the $x$ has to be in the domain of positive reals, since $ln(x)$ would otherwise be undefined.

Now, if we take $$f(x)=\ln(x)+\arctan(x)-x+1$$

We find that $$f''(x) = \frac{-2x}{(x^2+1)^2}+\frac{-1}{x^2}$$

Since the denominators are always positive (squares) and the numerators are always negative, we have that

$$f''(x) < 0$$

And thus $f(x)$ is concave, and thus passes through any vertical line (here it would be $y=0$) at most twice.

Now, taking $f(0.1),f(1),f(10)$ would yield negative,positive,negative respectively, and applying intermediate value theorem suffices to show that indeed there are exactly two solutions.

Comment: Did you mean horizontal line ($y = 0$)?

Comment: yes i did mean $y=0$...

Comment: There is no need to determine the second derivative. The first derivative is decreasing asing, which implies concavity.

Comment: great explanation !!! thank you.